# hibernate criteria query order by join table field

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, hibernate-criteria, join

I use mysql database and have two tables `chapter` and `chapter_title_1`, there is a fk `chapter_id` in table `chapter_title_1` reference to table `chapter`.

[image: table chapter]  [image: table chapter_title_1]

Two entity class are `ChapterEntity.class` refer to table `chapter` and `ChapterTitle1Entity.class` refer to table `chapter_title_1`. There is a `List<ChapterTitle1Entity> chapterTitle1EntityList` in `ChapterEntity.class` annotated with `@OneToMany`. I want to get a list of `ChapterEntity` ordered by `ChapterEntity.sequence` **asc** and a list of `ChapterTitle1Entity` in each item of `ChapterEntity` ordered by `ChapterTitle1Entity.sequence` **desc**.

In my ADO layer I use criteria to query my database. I use the following code to get the list:

```
Criteria criteria = session().createCriteria(ChapterEntity.class, "chapter");
criteria.createAlias("chapter.chapterTitle1EntityList", "title1List");
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("chapter.sequence")).
        addOrder(Order.desc("title1List.sequence"));
List<ChapterEntity> chapterEntityList = criteria.list();
return chapterEntityList;
```

but no matter it is `addOrder(Order.desc("title1List.sequence")` or `addOrder(Order.asc("title1List.sequence")`, the order of List `ChapterTitle1Entity` remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
ChapterEntity.class

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER , mappedBy="ChapterEntity")
@OrderBy("sequence Desc")
List<ChapterTitle1Entity> chapterTitle1EntityList;
```

But the code will become globle for the list.

Comment: thank you very much, but the embarrassing thing is that I also want it order by `sequence asc` sometimes, so I use hibernate criteria to query my database.

Comment: Yes it will work If you will use your given criteria. Now you dont need to create any alias just use simple criteria using Order.asc("chapter.sequence").

Comment: sorry, no matter I use `Order.desc("title1List.sequence")` or `Order.asc("title1List.sequence")`, the result remain the same. It didn't work.